# Multiple Android Startups

Tags: security, backup, boot

I'm really new to this whole open source android thing, but I know there is a whole world of potential. I read in a book once that this guy had a phone where if he entered one password, it would load his personalized OS/version of phone with its own files and apps and such. But if he entered a different password, it would load up a decoy version of his phone with different files and apps and such. Is there an app like this? Or is it even possible?

Comment: UPDATE: I am on a Samsung Galaxy S7 if that helps

Answer (score 0):

I cannot remember at what Android version it was introduced, but certainly M and N (6 and 7) have support for [multiple local user accounts](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user.html).

So although there may well be 'apps' that can do this, most modern Android devices can do it out of the box.

On my Nexus 6P, when I pull down the quick settings menu, right at the top next to the date and time is a profile picture of me. If I click this, I'm then taken to the 'User' menu

Answer (score -1):

Yeah some part is true there is a app SwitchMe I currently use it 
It help me to run two android version for switching profile I have to reboot the phone but be careful if any thing goes wrong you will not be able to recover your data although it never happened to me
Also you need rooted phone and SuperSu as system app and enable allow root acess to guest user in setting of SuperSu

Wish u gud luck with that